# live text, fonts in pdf in node-canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, pdf, canvas

I am using node-canvas to create images from canvas elements.

I've got canvas with few elements and i want to make pdf file from them.
I've been able to create the pdf from the canvas but i don't get the live text and fonts in the pdf.

this is my code:

```
var filename = uuid.v4() + '.pdf';
var path = '/' + site + '/' + filename;

var out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + path);

var canvas = fabric.createCanvasForNode(designWidth, designHeight,'pdf');

canvas.loadFromJSON(jsonStr, function () {

  canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas);

  canvas.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;

  out.write(canvas.nodeCanvas.toBuffer(), function (err) {

    if (err) throw err

  });

});
```

my node version:

```
node-canvas v5.3.2

node v4.2.6
```

thanks